# How to add an Ubuntu entry to grub menu? (CentOS dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside CentOs 6.7. I did this without using a live cd or usb by mounting the iso image to a 1.3GB partition (sda3). I was able to add a grub entry and boot to the partition and install Ubuntu on some free space (sda4). However after reboot, I was not able to select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, I could only select CentOs and the Ubuntu Installer partition.
I have checked and seems that Ubuntu is properly installed in sda4 but I cannot access it. I tried adding a GRUB entry to (hd0,3) but that does not seem to work. Please note that I am using GRUB 0.97
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## Configuration File Structure

The GRUB menu interface configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. The commands to set the global preferences for the menu interface are placed at the top of the file, followed by stanzas for each operating kernel or operating system listed in the menu.

The following is a very basic GRUB menu configuration file designed to boot either Ubuntu Linux or else(centos legacy grub):

```
edit this file from centos terminal /boot/grub/menu.lst  and to find about which (hd*,0) echo this file /boot/grub/device.map if this dont work then lookup for locating grub2(ubuntu 14.04) from grub-legacy(centos-6.*)

default=0
timeout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz

# section to load Linux
#your current running os i.e. centos v6.7 running grub-legacy
title CentOS 6.7 Linux (---1.ent)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.21-1 ro root=/dev/sda2
    initrd /initrd-2.4.21-1.img

title Ubuntu
    root (hd0,2)
    # replace ? with filename of Ubuntu kernel image
    kernel /? root=/dev/sda3
```